# Influxdb 2.0.8 CLI remote access with basic auth

Tags: influxdb

Is there a way to connect to an Influx DB 2.0.8 remotely from Windows using the `influx` cli tool with basic auth (username and password)?

Cannot find anything in the documentation, it either requires a token or assumes the CLI is run on the same machine with InfluxDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLI for InfluxDB 2.x uses organization and token for authentication, rather than username and password.

See `influx config create --help` for information on how to set that up.

You can also add multiple credentials to the 2.x CLI, to allow switching back and forth between development and production, or whatever, using the `influx config` command.